# What are the physical implications of these BCs to the 1D heat equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, boundary-conditions

The heat equation in 1 dimension states that:
$$\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 T(x,t)}{\partial x^2}\, , \quad \alpha > 0$$
And my boundaries on a finite rod of length $L$ are:
\begin{align}
\partial_xT(x,t) = \partial_xT(L,t) = 0
\end{align}
What do they mean physically. Also what are the differences between the BC's above and below:
\begin{align}
\partial_xT(0,0) = \partial_xT(L,0) = 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first BC doesn't make any sense:

$$\begin{align}
T'(x,t) = T'(L,t) = 0
\end{align}$$

because $T'(x,t)=0$ means there's no heat flux at all, for any $x$. That's nonsensical. Note also that your BCs must be in partials because you're looking for a function $T(x,t)$

It should be:

$$\begin{align}
\partial_xT(0,t) = \partial_xT(L,t) = 0
\end{align}$$

Then it means that at all times $t$ there is no heat flow in or out of the points $x=0$ and $x=L$. I.o.w. the rod is perfectly insulated at both its ends.

Note that this is so because heat flux in $\text{1D}$ is given by:

$$q=-k\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial x}$$

As regards:

$$\begin{align}
\partial_xT(x,0) = \partial_xT(L,0) = 0
\end{align}$$

It's an initial condition but it makes little sense. A useful IC would be simply:

$$T(x,0)=f(x)$$

which describes the initial temperature distribution ($t=0$)